# Mysql Inner join - how to use value of first table column in join clause

Tags: mysql

In my "bookings" table, each booking has a number of persons and an "event_time" , which is one of three time slots which is bookable.

In my query I am trying to return how many free seats there are left for each restaurant and time slot (event_time number)

I select restaurants and do an INNER JOIN to include the bookings table, but I would need access to the "number_of_seats_max" column from the restaurants table **inside** the inner join, which does not seem possible.

Here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04c358/7).

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `restaurants` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `number_of_seats_max` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `event_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number_of_persons` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `restaurant_id` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

The below query works, but in this case I have hard coded "**80**" instead of the max seats column ( `r.number_of_seats_max` ). Thats the column I need to use. If you put  `r.number_of_seats_max` instead, you get the error "`unknown column`".

```
SELECT r.title, r.number_of_seats_max, innerquery.free_seats_left,
innerquery.num_persons_booked
FROM restaurants r
INNER JOIN(
    select 
        restaurant_id,
        SUM(number_of_persons) as num_persons_booked,
        (80 - SUM(number_of_persons)) AS free_seats_left   // <-- 80 is hard coded
        from bookings
        WHERE event_date = '2019-07-18'
        group by event_time,restaurant_id
        ORDER BY free_seats_left DESC

) as innerquery
     ON innerquery.restaurant_id = r.id;
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It's not possible to reference a table from the outer query from inside an inline view query. MySQL processes the the inline view query (i.e. the `( SELECT ... )` following `JOIN` ) first. MySQL calls the inline view a *derived table*. That makes sense when we understand how it's processed. Once the inline view query is materialized into a table, then the outer query can be executed, fetching rows from the derived table like it was a regular table. The inline view query gets executed one time, before any rows from `restaurant` is accessed. See the answer from Barmar.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04c358/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the subtraction in the main query, not the subquery.

```
SELECT r.title, innerquery.event_time, r.number_of_seats_max, 
        r.number_of_seats_max - innerquery.num_persons_booked AS free_seats_left,
        innerquery.num_persons_booked
FROM restaurants r
INNER JOIN(
    select 
        restaurant_id,
        event_time,
        SUM(number_of_persons) as num_persons_booked
    from bookings
    WHERE event_date = '2019-07-18'
    group by event_time,restaurant_id
) as innerquery
     ON innerquery.restaurant_id = r.id
ORDER BY free_seats_left DESC
```

I added `event_time` to the `SELECT` list of both the subquery and the main query, so you can show the available seats for each time slot.

Comment: the `order by` is going to need to be relocated to the outer query. i'm confused at including `event_time` in the `group by` in the inline view query. since thats not being returned to the outer query, with potential for multiple matching rows, we aren't going to be able to distinguish which row is for which event_time

Comment: @spencer7593 Good catch, I wasn't looking at the rest of it, just concentrating on the calculation. I added `event_time` to the results of both queries, as he said he wanted to find out how many seats are available at each time.